# Exception in JavaFx application changing Scene

Tags: java, javafx, exception, event-handling

I have following function with timer

```
private void doTime(){
    Timeline time = new Timeline();

    time.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
    if(time != null){
        time.stop();
    }
    KeyFrame frame = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event){
            timeT.decrement();
            Time.setText(timeT.getTime());
            if(timeT.getTime().equals("00:01:00")){
                Time.setTextFill(Color.web("#ab1313")); 
            }

            if(timeT.isZero()){
                time.stop();
                 resultExit();
            }
        }
    });
    time.getKeyFrames().add(frame);
    time.playFromStart();
}
```

I am having problem with resultExit function which contains the following lines of code

```
public void resultExit() throws Exception{
    Parent pane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("ResultPage.fxml"));
    Scene panechild = new Scene(pane);
    Stage app = (Stage)root.getScene().getWindow(); 
    app.hide();
    app.setScene(panechild);
    app.show();
}
```

The problem is handle function is giving error the unreported exception ,needed to be thrown or catch but if I do try catch then I cant change the scene how can I deal with it?

Comment: Maybe your FXML path is incorrect. Try `getResource("/ResultPage.fxml"));`

Comment: "If I do try-catch, I can't change the scene". Why not???